# Why is a comment not added for every close suggestion?

Tags: discussion

When I vote to close because of this reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

No comment to that effect appears for the OP as far as I can see. This is unlike a duplicate close suggestion.

This causes me to type something myself to that effect in a comment, otherwise the OP has less chance to correct before other's agree and close the question at which point the OP finally sees that message.

Why the difference in behaviour?

Comment: Why not? Because it would be annoying and have no benefits. It would make CVers pingable and outrage OP.

Comment: @bjb568 I stand by my close votes. Also CVers become pingable once the actual question is closed so your point is mute. Plus I explained the benefit, explains the fault before the question is actually closed.

Comment: mute != moot FYI

Comment: CVers do not become pingable, with the exception of binding vote (i.e., a mod vote or a gold-badge dupehammer). One can ping Glorfindel here, but not Paulie_D.

Comment: Cheers @matt lol

Comment: @zaq Just so I understand, you're saying if I comment @ Paulie_D here they simply wouldn't get the notification?

Comment: Nope...no *ping*

Comment: Correct. On the other hand, writing @Glorfindel would ping.